# Combining two columns with character strings into a new column

Tags: r

Below I have two columns of data (column 6 and 7) of genus and species names. I would like to combine those two columns with character string data into a new column with the names combined.

I am quite new to R and the code below does not work! Thank you for the help wonderful people of stack overflow!

```
#TRYING TO MIX GENUS & SPECIES COLUMN 
accepted_genus <- merged_subsets_2[6]
accepted_species <- merged_subsets_2[7]

accepted_genus
accepted_species

merged_subsets_2%>%
  bind_cols(accepted_genus, accepted_species)
merged_subsets_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate(Col3 = str_c(Col1, Col2))
```

---

Or with `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    unite(Col3, Col1, Col2, sep="", remove = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if this doesn't answer your question.

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = letters[1:2], Col2=LETTERS[1:2])  # Sample data
```

> ```
> > df
>   Col1 Col2
> 1    a    A
> 2    b    B
> ```

```
df$Col3 <- paste0(df$Col1, df$Col2)  # Without spacing
```

> ```
> > df
>   Col1 Col2 Col3
> 1    a    A   aA
> 2    b    B   bB
> ```

```
df$Col3 <- paste(df$Col1, df$Col2)
```

> ```
> > df
>   Col1 Col2 Col3
> 1    a    A  a A
> 2    b    B  b B
> ```